Ocean-themed animation TV show with a "digital" intro
This has bugged me for years! I'm hoping to find again a TV show that I saw in the late 90s / early 2000s. Some features of it I remember:

The protagonist is a young adolescent female, possibly a mermaid
The intro scene has a catchy tune and it is animated differently from the rest of the show itself: the intro features digital elements whereas the show is hand drawn
The intro features a starfish and hoops (which I think either dolphins or the main female character jumps through) and houses built on ocean edges
The characters are either Caucasian-looking or animals or fantastical creatures
The original language is most likely English although it has been dubbed into my native tongue

It's not The Little Mermaid (1992-1994).

@Richard Probably, indeed! :)
